# Is it possible to create a AWS lambda function by a JSON config file?

Tags: aws-lambda

When I execute

```
$ aws lambda list-functions
```

I get a list of all my lambda functions:

```
{
    "Functions": [
        {
            "TracingConfig": {
                "Mode": "PassThrough"
            },
            "Version": "$LATEST",
            "CodeSha256": "aB+/Defg0+abcdefghijklmnopqerstuvwxyzABCDEF=",
            "FunctionName": "foofunction",
            "VpcConfig": {
                "SubnetIds": [],
                "SecurityGroupIds": []
            },
            "MemorySize": 128,
            "RevisionId": "123abc45-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
            "CodeSize": 61521970,
            "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:foofunction",
            "Environment": {
                "Variables": {
                    "FOO": "BAR",
                    "ESCAPING": "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]",
                    "IS_VALUE": "1"
                }
            },
            "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/lamdaRole",
            "Timeout": 300,
            "LastModified": "2018-03-01T12:11:10.987+0000",
            "Runtime": "python3.6",
            "Description": ""
        }]
}
```

Is it possible to use this to create a new lambda function? I am looking for something like

```
$ aws lambda create-function --config myconfig.json
```

where `myconfig.json` would contain the name, environment variables, the region, the role, the handler, the runtime and a description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Execute the lambda command with the --generate-cli-skeleton option
   to view the JSON skeleton and direct the output to a file to save
   the skeleton locally:

   ```
   aws lambda create-function --generate-cli-skeleton > cli.json
   ```
2. Open the skeleton in a text editor and remove any parameters that
       you will not use and fill the parameters that you need.
3. Pass the JSON configuration to the --cli-input-json parameter using
       the file:// prefix

   ```
    aws lambda create-function --cli-input-json file://cli.json
   ```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/generate-cli-skeleton.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I was missing the "file://" part